# Numbers beside tags in my profile is inconsistent

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

I have noticed several of the numbers to the left of tags in my profile are inconsistent with the number that it shows when I hover my mouse:

For example, this tag has a 0 beside it but the tool-tip says 8:

[image: tags]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not. Your tag score is only from answers, so if you have no upvoted answers in the tag, your score will always be 0 (all of this being non-community-wiki of course). The stats for questions is provided in the tooltip just as a so-you-know.

Comment: So the number to the left of the tag is only for answers, not questions? Well, that isn't very intuitive. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To make this explicit for anyone else who finds this:

[image: tags with info]